# How do I set up a file on GitHub for download?

Tags: github, download

Does anyone know how to set up a file on GitHub that can be downloaded?

- files are text files (actually iCal calendar files).
- files are part of a GitHub repository, but I do not want to force the user to download/clone the entire project just to get one file.
- I do not want to force the user to click on a 'raw' link that displays the file in the browser (and then do a 'save as'), I want the user to click on a link and get the file downloaded to a disk file (or whatever their browser is set up to do with downloaded files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that GitHub doesn't offer an endpoint that forces downloads of files like this.  If you want to do this, I'd suggest one of two options:

- If these are part of a normal software release, then add them as a GitHub release asset and they should be able to be downloaded normally.  You may want to use the API to upload them in order to appropriately set the Content-Type value.
- If they aren't, then I'd set up a small server that provides the desired Content-Disposition and host them yourself.  If you're using these as part of some automated process, you'd probably need to do this anyway for rate-limiting reasons.

Comment: Thanks. I just added the files to the release.